# Views: Select nodes having a specific field empty

Tags: 7, views

I know how to create a filter to show nodes having a specific field empty, using *Is equal to* operator, But I want to expose this filter to visitor in form of checkbox. I want a check box for example with title "Show nodes that doesn't have an image".

Is it possible using Views 3?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [better exposed filters?](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters)